# android PopupWindow showAtLocation move with initial position

Tags: android, popupwindow

i have a popup and i want to initially put it on the right side of the screen BUT still allowing it to drag.

if i set gravity to center, i can move it just fine

```
LinearLayout l = initNoteLayout(context);
            mNotePopup = new PopupWindow(l, 650, 370, true);
            l.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                private int dx = 0;
                private int dy = 0;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            dx = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
                            dy = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
                            int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();
                            int left =  (x - dx);
                            int top =   (y - dy);
                            //Log.d("test", "x: " + left + " y: " + top);
                            mNotePopup.update(left, top, -1, -1);
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            });
            mNotePopup.showAtLocation(l, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

this works but its in the center of the screen. if i set

```
mNotePopup.showAtLocation(l, Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
```

it show up where i want it and i can drag it up and down BUT it's glued to the right side.

any ideas? i've tried every combination of Gravity flags i can think of

thanks

Comment: i just found an answer (didn't take long but may as well post for other people). i set mNotePopup.showAtLocation(l, Gravity.CENTER, 500, 500); so it offsets it down and right. 500 is a bit arbitrary, it could be any big number.